# Use cuda to get screenshot of visible application

Tags: windows, video, memory, cuda, framebuffer

I am owner of a Nvidia GTX 1060. I know that with Windows it is not possible to directly access the video memory of the graphics card. But I read somewhere on an email list that it is possible to fetch the pixels that are **displayed** right now on the monitor with use of the CUDA API. Unfortunately I found no code example for this.

What I want is something like an bitmap-like array containing the rgb values of the pixels

```
arr[0] = 255        // red
arr[1] = 255        // green
arr[2] = 0          // blue
arr[3] = 0          // alpha
arr[4] = 255
...
```

Can someone please show me an example how to do it with CUDA?

I know there is a way using DirectX or openGL. I already tried it out but it is either too complex or too slow and won't work with fullscreen and windowed applications at the same time.

Comment: No, it's not possible with CUDA.  You need to use a graphics API like DirectX or OGL.

Comment: I guess you shouldn't believe everything you read in email..

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is not only impossible, it may be even seen as a security flaw. In general, one application should not be able to retrieve the shown window of another application without some kind of consent and control from the operating system.

I remember reading about exactly that kind of a flaw few years ago, but I couldn't find the article anymore. However, there are many other articles discussing similar issues. For example in:

http://ece.neu.edu/groups/nucar/NUCARTALKS/snp14-gpusteal.pdf

they discuss GPU vulnerabilities allowing a malicious program to partially reconstruct a webpage shown in Chromium.

Comment: Wow that sounds like very good evening read. Don't be afraid ... I just want to build a selfmade ambilight without a hardware capture device. Nothing criminal.